# scale_x_continuous : Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, continuous-delivery, discrete

I'm a beginner in R. I get this error

> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

when I try to use

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:10)
```

The plot I get is the following one. As you can see, the axis needs to be reduced...

[image: Plot with wrong axis]

I get my data from a csv file

```
dput(head(Data, 20))
structure(list(Pmanche = structure(1:20, .Label = c("0", "0,1", 
"0,2", "0,3", "0,4", "0,5", "0,6", "0,7", "0,8", "0,9", "1", 
"1,1", "1,2", "1,3", "1,4", "1,5", "1,6", "1,7", "1,8", "1,9", 
"10", "10,1", "10,2", "10,3", "10,4", "10,5", "10,6", "10,7", 
"10,8", "10,9", "100", "11", "11,1", "11,2", "11,3", "11,4", 
"11,5", "11,6", "11,7", "11,8", "11,9", "12", "12,1", "12,2", 
"12,3", "12,4", "12,5", "12,6", "12,7", "12,8", "12,9", "13", 
"13,1", "13,2", "13,3", "13,4", "13,5", "13,6", "13,7", "13,8", 
"13,9", "14", "14,1", "14,2", "14,3", "14,4", "14,5", "14,6", 
"14,7", "14,8", "14,9", "15", "15,1", "15,2", "15,3", "15,4", 
"15,5", "15,6", "15,7", "15,8", "15,9", "16", "16,1", "16,2", 
"16,3", "16,4", "16,5", "16,6", "16,7", "16,8", "16,9", "17", 
"17,1", "17,2", "17,3", "17,4", "17,5", "17,6", "17,7", "17,8", 
"17,9", "18", "18,1", "18,2", "18,3", "18,4", "18,5", "18,6", 
"18,7", "18,8", "18,9", "19", "19,1", "19,2", "19,3", "19,4", 
"19,5", "19,6", "19,7", "19,8", "19,9", "2", "2,1", "2,2", "2,3", 
"2,4", "2,5", "2,6", "2,7", "2,8", "2,9", "20", "20,1", "20,2", 
"20,3", "20,4", "20,5", "20,6", "20,7", "20,8", "20,9", "21", 
"21,1", "21,2", "21,3", "21,4", "21,5", "21,6", "21,7", "21,8", 
"21,9", "22", "22,1", "22,2", "22,3", "22,4", "22,5", "22,6", 
"22,7", "22,8", "22,9", "23", "23,1", "23,2", "23,3", "23,4", 
"23,5", "23,6", "23,7", "23,8", "23,9", "24", "24,1", "24,2", 
"24,3", "24,4", "24,5", "24,6", "24,7", "24,8", "24,9", "25", 
"25,1", "25,2", "25,3", "25,4", "25,5", "25,6", "25,7", "25,8", 
"25,9", "26", "26,1", "26,2", "26,3", "26,4", "26,5", "26,6", 
"26,7", "26,8", "26,9", "27", "27,1", "27,2", "27,3", "27,4", 
"27,5", "27,6", "27,7", "27,8", "27,9", "28", "28,1", "28,2", 
"28,3", "28,4", "28,5", "28,6", "28,7", "28,8", "28,9", "29", 
"29,1", "29,2", "29,3", "29,4", "29,5", "29,6", "29,7", "29,8", 
"29,9", "3", "3,1", "3,2", "3,3", "3,4", "3,5", "3,6", "3,7", 
"3,8", "3,9", "30", "30,1", "30,2", "30,3", "30,4", "30,5", "30,6", 
"30,7", "30,8", "30,9", "31", "31,1", "31,2", "31,3", "31,4", 
"31,5", "31,6", "31,7", "31,8", "31,9", "32", "32,1", "32,2", 
"32,3", "32,4", "32,5", "32,6", "32,7", "32,8", "32,9", "33", 
"33,1", "33,2", "33,3", "33,4", "33,5", "33,6", "33,7", "33,8", 
"33,9", "34", "34,1", "34,2", "34,3", "34,4", "34,5", "34,6", 
"34,7", "34,8", "34,9", "35", "35,1", "35,2", "35,3", "35,4", 
"35,5", "35,6", "35,7", "35,8", "35,9", "36", "36,1", "36,2", 
"36,3", "36,4", "36,5", "36,6", "36,7", "36,8", "36,9", "37", 
"37,1", "37,2", "37,3", "37,4", "37,5", "37,6", "37,7", "37,8", 
"37,9", "38", "38,1", "38,2", "38,3", "38,4", "38,5", "38,6", 
"38,7", "38,8", "38,9", "39", "39,1", "39,2", "39,3", "39,4", 
"39,5", "39,6", "39,7", "39,8", "39,9", "4", "4,1", "4,2", "4,3", 
"4,4", "4,5", "4,6", "4,7", "4,8", "4,9", "40", "40,1", "40,2", 
"40,3", "40,4", "40,5", "40,6", "40,7", "40,8", "40,9", "41", 
"41,1", "41,2", "41,3", "41,4", "41,5", "41,6", "41,7", "41,8", 
"41,9", "42", "42,1", "42,2", "42,3", "42,4", "42,5", "42,6", 
"42,7", "42,8", "42,9", "43", "43,1", "43,2", "43,3", "43,4", 
"43,5", "43,6", "43,7", "43,8", "43,9", "44", "44,1", "44,2", 
"44,3", "44,4", "44,5", "44,6", "44,7", "44,8", "44,9", "45", 
"45,1", "45,2", "45,3", "45,4", "45,5", "45,6", "45,7", "45,8", 
"45,9", "46", "46,1", "46,2", "46,3", "46,4", "46,5", "46,6", 
"46,7", "46,8", "46,9", "47", "47,1", "47,2", "47,3", "47,4", 
"47,5", "47,6", "47,7", "47,8", "47,9", "48", "48,1", "48,2", 
"48,3", "48,4", "48,5", "48,6", "48,7", "48,8", "48,9", "49", 
"49,1", "49,2", "49,3", "49,4", "49,5", "49,6", "49,7", "49,8", 
"49,9", "5", "5,1", "5,2", "5,3", "5,4", "5,5", "5,6", "5,7", 
"5,8", "5,9", "50", "50,1", "50,2", "50,3", "50,4", "50,5", "50,6", 
"50,7", "50,8", "50,9", "51", "51,1", "51,2", "51,3", "51,4", 
"51,5", "51,6", "51,7", "51,8", "51,9", "52", "52,1", "52,2", 
"52,3", "52,4", "52,5", "52,6", "52,7", "52,8", "52,9", "53", 
"53,1", "53,2", "53,3", "53,4", "53,5", "53,6", "53,7", "53,8", 
"53,9", "54", "54,1", "54,2", "54,3", "54,4", "54,5", "54,6", 
"54,7", "54,8", "54,9", "55", "55,1", "55,2", "55,3", "55,4", 
"55,5", "55,6", "55,7", "55,8", "55,9", "56", "56,1", "56,2", 
"56,3", "56,4", "56,5", "56,6", "56,7", "56,8", "56,9", "57", 
"57,1", "57,2", "57,3", "57,4", "57,5", "57,6", "57,7", "57,8", 
"57,9", "58", "58,1", "58,2", "58,3", "58,4", "58,5", "58,6", 
"58,7", "58,8", "58,9", "59", "59,1", "59,2", "59,3", "59,4", 
"59,5", "59,6", "59,7", "59,8", "59,9", "6", "6,1", "6,2", "6,3", 
"6,4", "6,5", "6,6", "6,7", "6,8", "6,9", "60", "60,1", "60,2", 
"60,3", "60,4", "60,5", "60,6", "60,7", "60,8", "60,9", "61", 
"61,1", "61,2", "61,3", "61,4", "61,5", "61,6", "61,7", "61,8", 
"61,9", "62", "62,1", "62,2", "62,3", "62,4", "62,5", "62,6", 
"62,7", "62,8", "62,9", "63", "63,1", "63,2", "63,3", "63,4", 
"63,5", "63,6", "63,7", "63,8", "63,9", "64", "64,1", "64,2", 
"64,3", "64,4", "64,5", "64,6", "64,7", "64,8", "64,9", "65", 
"65,1", "65,2", "65,3", "65,4", "65,5", "65,6", "65,7", "65,8", 
"65,9", "66", "66,1", "66,2", "66,3", "66,4", "66,5", "66,6", 
"66,7", "66,8", "66,9", "67", "67,1", "67,2", "67,3", "67,4", 
"67,5", "67,6", "67,7", "67,8", "67,9", "68", "68,1", "68,2", 
"68,3", "68,4", "68,5", "68,6", "68,7", "68,8", "68,9", "69", 
"69,1", "69,2", "69,3", "69,4", "69,5", "69,6", "69,7", "69,8", 
"69,9", "7", "7,1", "7,2", "7,3", "7,4", "7,5", "7,6", "7,7", 
"7,8", "7,9", "70", "70,1", "70,2", "70,3", "70,4", "70,5", "70,6", 
"70,7", "70,8", "70,9", "71", "71,1", "71,2", "71,3", "71,4", 
"71,5", "71,6", "71,7", "71,8", "71,9", "72", "72,1", "72,2", 
"72,3", "72,4", "72,5", "72,6", "72,7", "72,8", "72,9", "73", 
"73,1", "73,2", "73,3", "73,4", "73,5", "73,6", "73,7", "73,8", 
"73,9", "74", "74,1", "74,2", "74,3", "74,4", "74,5", "74,6", 
"74,7", "74,8", "74,9", "75", "75,1", "75,2", "75,3", "75,4", 
"75,5", "75,6", "75,7", "75,8", "75,9", "76", "76,1", "76,2", 
"76,3", "76,4", "76,5", "76,6", "76,7", "76,8", "76,9", "77", 
"77,1", "77,2", "77,3", "77,4", "77,5", "77,6", "77,7", "77,8", 
"77,9", "78", "78,1", "78,2", "78,3", "78,4", "78,5", "78,6", 
"78,7", "78,8", "78,9", "79", "79,1", "79,2", "79,3", "79,4", 
"79,5", "79,6", "79,7", "79,8", "79,9", "8", "8,1", "8,2", "8,3", 
"8,4", "8,5", "8,6", "8,7", "8,8", "8,9", "80", "80,1", "80,2", 
"80,3", "80,4", "80,5", "80,6", "80,7", "80,8", "80,9", "81", 
"81,1", "81,2", "81,3", "81,4", "81,5", "81,6", "81,7", "81,8", 
"81,9", "82", "82,1", "82,2", "82,3", "82,4", "82,5", "82,6", 
"82,7", "82,8", "82,9", "83", "83,1", "83,2", "83,3", "83,4", 
"83,5", "83,6", "83,7", "83,8", "83,9", "84", "84,1", "84,2", 
"84,3", "84,4", "84,5", "84,6", "84,7", "84,8", "84,9", "85", 
"85,1", "85,2", "85,3", "85,4", "85,5", "85,6", "85,7", "85,8", 
"85,9", "86", "86,1", "86,2", "86,3", "86,4", "86,5", "86,6", 
"86,7", "86,8", "86,9", "87", "87,1", "87,2", "87,3", "87,4", 
"87,5", "87,6", "87,7", "87,8", "87,9", "88", "88,1", "88,2", 
"88,3", "88,4", "88,5", "88,6", "88,7", "88,8", "88,9", "89", 
"89,1", "89,2", "89,3", "89,4", "89,5", "89,6", "89,7", "89,8", 
"89,9", "9", "9,1", "9,2", "9,3", "9,4", "9,5", "9,6", "9,7", 
"9,8", "9,9", "90", "90,1", "90,2", "90,3", "90,4", "90,5", "90,6", 
"90,7", "90,8", "90,9", "91", "91,1", "91,2", "91,3", "91,4", 
"91,5", "91,6", "91,7", "91,8", "91,9", "92", "92,1", "92,2", 
"92,3", "92,4", "92,5", "92,6", "92,7", "92,8", "92,9", "93", 
"93,1", "93,2", "93,3", "93,4", "93,5", "93,6", "93,7", "93,8", 
"93,9", "94", "94,1", "94,2", "94,3", "94,4", "94,5", "94,6", 
"94,7", "94,8", "94,9", "95", "95,1", "95,2", "95,3", "95,4", 
"95,5", "95,6", "95,7", "95,8", "95,9", "96", "96,1", "96,2", 
"96,3", "96,4", "96,5", "96,6", "96,7", "96,8", "96,9", "97", 
"97,1", "97,2", "97,3", "97,4", "97,5", "97,6", "97,7", "97,8", 
"97,9", "98", "98,1", "98,2", "98,3", "98,4", "98,5", "98,6", 
"98,7", "98,8", "98,9", "99", "99,1", "99,2", "99,3", "99,4", 
"99,5", "99,6", "99,7", "99,8", "99,9"), class = "factor"), Pcsge = structure(1:20, .Label = c("0", 
"0,1", "0,2", "0,3", "0,4", "0,5", "0,6", "0,7", "0,8", "0,9", 
"1", "1,1", "1,2", "1,3", "1,4", "1,5", "1,6", "1,7", "1,8", 
"1,9", "10", "10,1", "10,2", "10,3", "10,4", "10,5", "10,6", 
"10,7", "10,8", "10,9", "100", "11", "11,1", "11,2", "11,3", 
"11,4", "11,5", "11,6", "11,7", "11,8", "11,9", "12", "12,1", 
"12,2", "12,3", "12,4", "12,5", "12,6", "12,7", "12,8", "12,9", 
"13", "13,1", "13,2", "13,3", "13,4", "13,5", "13,6", "13,7", 
"13,8", "13,9", "14", "14,1", "14,2", "14,3", "14,4", "14,5", 
"14,6", "14,7", "14,8", "14,9", "15", "15,1", "15,2", "15,3", 
"15,4", "15,5", "15,6", "15,7", "15,8", "15,9", "16", "16,1", 
"16,2", "16,3", "16,4", "16,5", "16,6", "16,7", "16,8", "16,9", 
"17", "17,1", "17,2", "17,3", "17,4", "17,5", "17,6", "17,7", 
"17,8", "17,9", "18", "18,1", "18,2", "18,3", "18,4", "18,5", 
"18,6", "18,7", "18,8", "18,9", "19", "19,1", "19,2", "19,3", 
"19,4", "19,5", "19,6", "19,7", "19,8", "19,9", "2", "2,1", "2,2", 
"2,3", "2,4", "2,5", "2,6", "2,7", "2,8", "2,9", "20", "20,1", 
"20,2", "20,3", "20,4", "20,5", "20,6", "20,7", "20,8", "20,9", 
"21", "21,1", "21,2", "21,3", "21,4", "21,5", "21,6", "21,7", 
"21,8", "21,9", "22", "22,1", "22,2", "22,3", "22,4", "22,5", 
"22,6", "22,7", "22,8", "22,9", "23", "23,1", "23,2", "23,3", 
"23,4", "23,5", "23,6", "23,7", "23,8", "23,9", "24", "24,1", 
"24,2", "24,3", "24,4", "24,5", "24,6", "24,7", "24,8", "24,9", 
"25", "25,1", "25,2", "25,3", "25,4", "25,5", "25,6", "25,7", 
"25,8", "25,9", "26", "26,1", "26,2", "26,3", "26,4", "26,5", 
"26,6", "26,7", "26,8", "26,9", "27", "27,1", "27,2", "27,3", 
"27,4", "27,5", "27,6", "27,7", "27,8", "27,9", "28", "28,1", 
"28,2", "28,3", "28,4", "28,5", "28,6", "28,7", "28,8", "28,9", 
"29", "29,1", "29,2", "29,3", "29,4", "29,5", "29,6", "29,7", 
"29,8", "29,9", "3", "3,1", "3,2", "3,3", "3,4", "3,5", "3,6", 
"3,7", "3,8", "3,9", "30", "30,1", "30,2", "30,3", "30,4", "30,5", 
"30,6", "30,7", "30,8", "30,9", "31", "31,1", "31,2", "31,3", 
"31,4", "31,5", "31,6", "31,7", "31,8", "31,9", "32", "32,1", 
"32,2", "32,3", "32,4", "32,5", "32,6", "32,7", "32,8", "32,9", 
"33", "33,1", "33,2", "33,3", "33,4", "33,5", "33,6", "33,7", 
"33,8", "33,9", "34", "34,1", "34,2", "34,3", "34,4", "34,5", 
"34,6", "34,7", "34,8", "34,9", "35", "35,1", "35,2", "35,3", 
"35,4", "35,5", "35,6", "35,7", "35,8", "35,9", "36", "36,1", 
"36,2", "36,3", "36,4", "36,5", "36,6", "36,7", "36,8", "36,9", 
"37", "37,1", "37,2", "37,3", "37,4", "37,5", "37,6", "37,7", 
"37,8", "37,9", "38", "38,1", "38,2", "38,3", "38,4", "38,5", 
"38,6", "38,7", "38,8", "38,9", "39", "39,1", "39,2", "39,3", 
"39,4", "39,5", "39,6", "39,7", "39,8", "39,9", "4", "4,1", "4,2", 
"4,3", "4,4", "4,5", "4,6", "4,7", "4,8", "4,9", "40", "40,1", 
"40,2", "40,3", "40,4", "40,5", "40,6", "40,7", "40,8", "40,9", 
"41", "41,1", "41,2", "41,3", "41,4", "41,5", "41,6", "41,7", 
"41,8", "41,9", "42", "42,1", "42,2", "42,3", "42,4", "42,5", 
"42,6", "42,7", "42,8", "42,9", "43", "43,1", "43,2", "43,3", 
"43,4", "43,5", "43,6", "43,7", "43,8", "43,9", "44", "44,1", 
"44,2", "44,3", "44,4", "44,5", "44,6", "44,7", "44,8", "44,9", 
"45", "45,1", "45,2", "45,3", "45,4", "45,5", "45,6", "45,7", 
"45,8", "45,9", "46", "46,1", "46,2", "46,3", "46,4", "46,5", 
"46,6", "46,7", "46,8", "46,9", "47", "47,1", "47,2", "47,3", 
"47,4", "47,5", "47,6", "47,7", "47,8", "47,9", "48", "48,1", 
"48,2", "48,3", "48,4", "48,5", "48,6", "48,7", "48,8", "48,9", 
"49", "49,1", "49,2", "49,3", "49,4", "49,5", "49,6", "49,7", 
"49,8", "49,9", "5", "5,1", "5,2", "5,3", "5,4", "5,5", "5,6", 
"5,7", "5,8", "5,9", "50", "50,1", "50,2", "50,3", "50,4", "50,5", 
"50,6", "50,7", "50,8", "50,9", "51", "51,1", "51,2", "51,3", 
"51,4", "51,5", "51,6", "51,7", "51,8", "51,9", "52", "52,1", 
"52,2", "52,3", "52,4", "52,5", "52,6", "52,7", "52,8", "52,9", 
"53", "53,1", "53,2", "53,3", "53,4", "53,5", "53,6", "53,7", 
"53,8", "53,9", "54", "54,1", "54,2", "54,3", "54,4", "54,5", 
"54,6", "54,7", "54,8", "54,9", "55", "55,1", "55,2", "55,3", 
"55,4", "55,5", "55,6", "55,7", "55,8", "55,9", "56", "56,1", 
"56,2", "56,3", "56,4", "56,5", "56,6", "56,7", "56,8", "56,9", 
"57", "57,1", "57,2", "57,3", "57,4", "57,5", "57,6", "57,7", 
"57,8", "57,9", "58", "58,1", "58,2", "58,3", "58,4", "58,5", 
"58,6", "58,7", "58,8", "58,9", "59", "59,1", "59,2", "59,3", 
"59,4", "59,5", "59,6", "59,7", "59,8", "59,9", "6", "6,1", "6,2", 
"6,3", "6,4", "6,5", "6,6", "6,7", "6,8", "6,9", "60", "60,1", 
"60,2", "60,3", "60,4", "60,5", "60,6", "60,7", "60,8", "60,9", 
"61", "61,1", "61,2", "61,3", "61,4", "61,5", "61,6", "61,7", 
"61,8", "61,9", "62", "62,1", "62,2", "62,3", "62,4", "62,5", 
"62,6", "62,7", "62,8", "62,9", "63", "63,1", "63,2", "63,3", 
"63,4", "63,5", "63,6", "63,7", "63,8", "63,9", "64", "64,1", 
"64,2", "64,3", "64,4", "64,5", "64,6", "64,7", "64,8", "64,9", 
"65", "65,1", "65,2", "65,3", "65,4", "65,5", "65,6", "65,7", 
"65,8", "65,9", "66", "66,1", "66,2", "66,3", "66,4", "66,5", 
"66,6", "66,7", "66,8", "66,9", "67", "67,1", "67,2", "67,3", 
"67,4", "67,5", "67,6", "67,7", "67,8", "67,9", "68", "68,1", 
"68,2", "68,3", "68,4", "68,5", "68,6", "68,7", "68,8", "68,9", 
"69", "69,1", "69,2", "69,3", "69,4", "69,5", "69,6", "69,7", 
"69,8", "69,9", "7", "7,1", "7,2", "7,3", "7,4", "7,5", "7,6", 
"7,7", "7,8", "7,9", "70", "70,1", "70,2", "70,3", "70,4", "70,5", 
"70,6", "70,7", "70,8", "70,9", "71", "71,1", "71,2", "71,3", 
"71,4", "71,5", "71,6", "71,7", "71,8", "71,9", "72", "72,1", 
"72,2", "72,3", "72,4", "72,5", "72,6", "72,7", "72,8", "72,9", 
"73", "73,1", "73,2", "73,3", "73,4", "73,5", "73,6", "73,7", 
"73,8", "73,9", "74", "74,1", "74,2", "74,3", "74,4", "74,5", 
"74,6", "74,7", "74,8", "74,9", "75", "75,1", "75,2", "75,3", 
"75,4", "75,5", "75,6", "75,7", "75,8", "75,9", "76", "76,1", 
"76,2", "76,3", "76,4", "76,5", "76,6", "76,7", "76,8", "76,9", 
"77", "77,1", "77,2", "77,3", "77,4", "77,5", "77,6", "77,7", 
"77,8", "77,9", "78", "78,1", "78,2", "78,3", "78,4", "78,5", 
"78,6", "78,7", "78,8", "78,9", "79", "79,1", "79,2", "79,3", 
"79,4", "79,5", "79,6", "79,7", "79,8", "79,9", "8", "8,1", "8,2", 
"8,3", "8,4", "8,5", "8,6", "8,7", "8,8", "8,9", "80", "80,1", 
"80,2", "80,3", "80,4", "80,5", "80,6", "80,7", "80,8", "80,9", 
"81", "81,1", "81,2", "81,3", "81,4", "81,5", "81,6", "81,7", 
"81,8", "81,9", "82", "82,1", "82,2", "82,3", "82,4", "82,5", 
"82,6", "82,7", "82,8", "82,9", "83", "83,1", "83,2", "83,3", 
"83,4", "83,5", "83,6", "83,7", "83,8", "83,9", "84", "84,1", 
"84,2", "84,3", "84,4", "84,5", "84,6", "84,7", "84,8", "84,9", 
"85", "85,1", "85,2", "85,3", "85,4", "85,5", "85,6", "85,7", 
"85,8", "85,9", "86", "86,1", "86,2", "86,3", "86,4", "86,5", 
"86,6", "86,7", "86,8", "86,9", "87", "87,1", "87,2", "87,3", 
"87,4", "87,5", "87,6", "87,7", "87,8", "87,9", "88", "88,1", 
"88,2", "88,3", "88,4", "88,5", "88,6", "88,7", "88,8", "88,9", 
"89", "89,1", "89,2", "89,3", "89,4", "89,5", "89,6", "89,7", 
"89,8", "89,9", "9", "9,1", "9,2", "9,3", "9,4", "9,5", "9,6", 
"9,7", "9,8", "9,9", "90", "90,1", "90,2", "90,3", "90,4", "90,5", 
"90,6", "90,7", "90,8", "90,9", "91", "91,1", "91,2", "91,3", 
"91,4", "91,5", "91,6", "91,7", "91,8", "91,9", "92", "92,1", 
"92,2", "92,3", "92,4", "92,5", "92,6", "92,7", "92,8", "92,9", 
"93", "93,1", "93,2", "93,3", "93,4", "93,5", "93,6", "93,7", 
"93,8", "93,9", "94", "94,1", "94,2", "94,3", "94,4", "94,5", 
"94,6", "94,7", "94,8", "94,9", "95", "95,1", "95,2", "95,3", 
"95,4", "95,5", "95,6", "95,7", "95,8", "95,9", "96", "96,1", 
"96,2", "96,3", "96,4", "96,5", "96,6", "96,7", "96,8", "96,9", 
"97", "97,1", "97,2", "97,3", "97,4", "97,5", "97,6", "97,7", 
"97,8", "97,9", "98", "98,1", "98,2", "98,3", "98,4", "98,5", 
"98,6", "98,7", "98,8", "98,9", "99", "99,1", "99,2", "99,3", 
"99,4", "99,5", "99,6", "99,7", "99,8", "99,9"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

At first, I though it was a problem with class of variables (numeric, factor...) but even when I convert to numeric it doesnt work...

```
Data$Pmanche <- levels(Data$Pmanche)[Data$Pmanche]
Data$Pcsge   <- levels(Data$Pcsge)[Data$Pcsge]
```

Thanks for your time!

Here is my code:

```
## definition workdirectory
setwd(dir="C:/Users/F596028/Documents/nouveau dossier/Optimisation")

##############################
# Packages                   #
##############################
# Graphics
#install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)


##############################
# ouverture du fichier Excel #
##############################

## Fichiers extension .csv du repertoir
files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$")
files <- sort(files)

## Enregistrement des titres
headers <- read.csv("Classeur1.csv", header = F, nrows = 1, as.is = T, sep=";")

## Enregistrement des données
Sub1 <- read.csv(files, skip=1, header=F, sep=";")
colnames(Sub1)=headers

Pmanche<-Sub1[,c(3)]
Pcsge<-Sub1[,c(4)]

Data <- data.frame(Pmanche,Pcsge)
##############################
# Plots  #
##############################
#Data$Pmanche <- levels(Data$Pmanche)[Data$Pmanche]
#Data$Pcsge   <- levels(Data$Pcsge)[Data$Pcsge]

p<- ggplot(Data, aes(Pmanche,Pcsge))
p + geom_point() + scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:10)
```

Comment: Please post the output of `dput(head(Data, 20))` in the question, there's not much we can do without data.

Comment: You might remove your rm(list(ls()), for people who are copying and pasting.

Comment: It looks like your x axis is still a factor. I don't see any attempt to make it numeric in your code

Comment: I put my data via dput(head(Data,20)).
I attent to make Data to numeric via (but doesnt work)
Data$Pmanche <- levels(Data$Pmanche)[Data$Pmanche]
Data$Pcsge   <- levels(Data$Pmanche)[Data$Pmanche]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it.
The problem was the data source.
I learned we need to be careful when taking data from excel... Decimals must be indicated with "." and not ","
Thanks